# Windows8 slideshow API

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, slideshow

I'm learning Windows8 programing and want to develop Photo SlideShow application with C#/Xaml.
I could get picures list in code behind, but I don't know how to display these pictures and control images transistion.

I want to control pictures like preinstalled 'Photo' windows8 app.
Is there good API and control for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [FlipView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR242678) would be a good candidate here; see [Adding FlipView Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh780617.aspx) for more insight.

There is a [FlipView control sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/FlipView-control-sample-18e434b4) on the [Windows Dev Center](http://dev.windows.com), but it does appear that only the JavaScript code is downloadable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I could do what I want, and [Flip pictures automatically in windows 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14177037/flip-pictures-automatically-in-windows-8) is also useful.